# AngularJS Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

I am using AngularJS, I have a function in a service with nested promises:

```
this.getOfferStatus = function (offer) {

    if(offer.isDraft){
        return 'Draft';
    } else {
        this.isProcessed(offer).then(function (isProcessed) {
            if (isProcessed) {
                this.isAccepted(offer).then(function (isAccepted) {
                    if (isAccepted) {
                        if (isExpired(offer)) {
                            return 'Expired';
                        } else {
                            if (this.isActive(offer).then(function (isActive) {
                                    return 'Active';
                                }, function (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                }));
                            }
                        } else {
                            return 'Rejected';
                        }
                    }, function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    })
                } else {
                    return 'Pending';
                }
            }, function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I call this function in my controller, I get this error:

> XHR finished loading: GET
>   "http://localhost:8080/localbusiness/1/offers/Absolute". Error:
>   [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
>       at angular.js:68
>       at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16702)
>       at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16928)
>       at done (angular.js:11266)
>       at completeRequest (angular.js:11464)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11405) Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

---

### isProcessed() function:

```
this.isProcessed = function (offer) { 
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var LocalBusinessResource =
        $resource(apiService + '/offers/:id/processed', {id: '@id'});
    LocalBusinessResource.get({id: offer.id}, function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result); 
    }, function (err) { 
        return $q.reject(err);
        alert('check your server connection ' + angular.toJson(err)); 
    });
    return deferred.promise; 
}
```

---

### In my controller:

```
$scope.getStatus = function(offer){ 
    return offerService.getOfferStatus(offer);
};
```

Comment: Don't return anything before function end. return after all your function executed.

Comment: You're also trying to return bare strings instead of resolved promises; that isn't going to work either.

Comment: @ArunShinde do you have any fixes?

Comment: What does `isProcessed()` do? I suspect that is creating an infinite recursive loop. Also using the `this` keyword inside a fulfillment handler of a `.then` method won't work. The promise spec says that the `this` keyword should be undefined in strict mode and the global context in sloppy mode.

Comment: @georgeawg here is isProcessed() function:                        this.isProcessed = function (offer) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var LocalBusinessResource = $resource(apiService + '/offers/:id/processed', {id: '@id'});
        LocalBusinessResource.get({id: offer.id}, function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function (err) {
            return $q.reject(err);
            alert('check your server connection ' + angular.toJson(err));
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

Comment: It would be better if you add your  controller code as well, or the portion of it where your calling `getOfferStatus`.

Comment: In my controller:                                                                           $scope.getStatus = function(offer){
            return offerService.getOfferStatus(offer);
        }

Comment: I see plenty of problems with this code but I don't see anything that would cause an infinite digest error. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? What do you expect `getOfferStaus` to return?

Comment: @georgeawg I expect getOfferStatus to return a string

Answer (score 0):

Check this might solve your problem.

```
this.getOfferStatus = function (offer) {
   var parent = this;
    if(offer.isDraft){
        parent.setStatus('Draft')
    }else{
        this.isProcessed(offer).then(function (isProcessed) {
            if (isProcessed) {
                this.isAccepted(offer).then(function (isAccepted) {
                    if (isAccepted) {
                        if (isExpired(offer)) {
                            parent.setStatus('Expired')
                        } else {
                            if (this.isActive(offer).then(function (isActive) {
                                    parent.setStatus('Active')
                                }, function (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                }));
                        }
                    }else{
                        parent.setStatus('Rejected')
                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }) 
            } else {
                parent.setStatus('Pending')
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

}

this.setStatus = function(status){
    $scope.status = status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> @georgeawg I expect getOfferStatus to return a string

The function only returns a string when `offer.isDraft` is truthy otherwise it returns `null`.

```
this.getOfferStatus = function (offer) {

    if(offer.isDraft){
        //Returns a string here
        return 'Draft';
    }else{
        this.isProcessed(offer).then(function anon1(isProcessed) {
            if (isProcessed) {
                this.isAccepted(offer).then(function anon2(isAccepted) {
                    if (isAccepted) {
                        if (isExpired(offer)) {
                            //This returns to function anon2
                            return 'Expired';
                        } else {
                            if (this.isActive(offer).then(function anon3(isActive) {
                                    //This returns to anon3
                                    return 'Active';
                                }));
                        }
                    }else{
                        //This returns to anon2
                        return 'Rejected';
                    }
                })
            } else {
                //This returns to anon1
                return 'Pending';
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
//
//Returns null here
//
}
```

There is only one `return` statement that returns to `getOfferStatus`. All the other `return` statements are inside anonymous functions inside `.then` methods.

It is erroneous to think those `return` statements will return a string to a parent (or grandparent) function. Returns need to be done for every level of nesting.